# Stop Spanish characters from getting converted into html

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, character-encoding, special-characters

I have seen this type of question asked multiple times and I've tried all the answers but had no luck so far;

The problem is when I try to send an email (I am using Zend Mail) with special characters in recipient name, it gets converted into html for e.g. A user is named `Mateo Julián` which gets replaced as `Mateo Juli&aacute;n`

I have tried `html_entity_decode` but had no success, added `UTF-8` header and meta but they didn't work either. And one point to be noted is that I am facing this issue only while sending emails. Added `UTF-8` also to mail object like this.

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
```

and it is called as

```
$mail->setBodyHtml($recipient_info['message'])
        ->setFrom($recipient_info["sender"]['email'],$recipient_info["sender"]['name'])
        ->addTo($recipient_info["receiver"]['email'],$blabla)// $blabla is the problem area where I send the name of recipient.
        ->setSubject($recipient_info['subject']);
```

Comment: Still the same issue and also email has designed template for which I will need setBodyHtml.